# how can Python see changes made to MariaDB by another client?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, commit

On my Windows machine, I have a very simple database on MariaDB (10.3.7) to which I connect with the mysql-connector-python-rf (2.2.2).

I also connect to the database with 2 instances of HeidiSQL workbench.

When I add or delete a line in a data table using one of the work benches, I can immediately access the changed data with a SELECT statement in the other work bench. My conclusion: the first work bench has already committed the change to the data base.

However, seeing the change in Python seems more complicated. I have to add a `commit()` before the query to see the changes:

```
config = {'user'    : 'some_user',
          'password': 'some_password',
          'host'    : '127.0.0.1',
          'database': 'some_database',
          'raise_on_warnings': True,
         }
db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

# wait some to make changes to the database using the HeidiSQL workbenches

db.commit() # even though Python has not changed anything which needs to be 
            # committed, this seems necessary to re-read the db to catch 
            # the changes that were committed by the other clients
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('some_SQL_query')
for result in cursor:
    do_something_with(result)
cursor.close()
```

So far I thought `commit()` is used to commit changes that Python wants to make to the database.

Is it correct to say that `commit()` also reads changes into Python that were done by other clients since the last `connect()`? Is this a bug/inconvenience or a feature?

Or is something else going on here that I am missing?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "transaction isolation level" (starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems))

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Interesting ... but isn't this related to concurrent transactions? In my case, the transactions are sequential (mainly due to my limited processing speed with mouse and keyboard). Workbench 1 changes and commits, Pause, Workbench 2 sees the change, Pause, Python does not see the change until I commit() in Python. Does this mean Python is caching the data until commit() forces it to refresh the cache?

Comment: you didn't search enough. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread *writing* issues `COMMIT` *after writing*.  Doing the `COMMIT` in the reading thread has no effect.

I would not change the "isolation level" unless you need for the reader to see unfinished changes while they are happening.  *This is not normally required.*

So, the *writer* should issue `COMMIT` as soon as it has finished some unit of work.  That might be a single `INSERT`; it might be a long, complicated, combination of operations.  A simple example is the classic 'transfer of funds:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE id = 123; -- my account
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 100 WHERE id = 432; -- your account
COMMIT;
```

For the integrity of `accounts` you want both `UPDATEs` to either happen nor not, even if the system crashes in the middle.  And you don't want any other thread to see an inconsistency in `balance` if it *reads* the data in the middle.

Another way to phrase it:  The *writer* is responsible for saying "I'm done" (by calling `commit`).

Comment: That is what I thought: I only need to `commit()` once I ask Python to **change** something in the database. But once Python has connected to the MariaDB database, Python seems to read the data from a snapshot (or something like this) that does not reflect changes which **other** clients will make and commit. Only after I `commit()` before **reading** in Python can I see those commits from the other clients. Currently I believe this is a side effect of the `REPEATABLE READ` transactions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Olaf - What you say seems correct.  And the "transaction isolation" (such as `REPEATABLE READ`) affects it.  I almost never find any need to change the isolation mode.  Also, check the value of `autocommit`.

Comment: `connection_object.autocommit = True` property does indeed do the trick as well and `connection_object.commit()` is not longer necessary before reading changes that were commited from other clients.

Answer (score 0):

As @brunodesthuilliers has pointed out, the answer seems to be in the isolation levels. The default for Python seems to be `REPEATABLE READ`. To always read the latest commits it is necessary to change the transactions' isolation level, e.g. to `READ COMMITTED`.

```
config = {'user'    : 'some_user',
          'password': 'some_password',
          'host'    : '127.0.0.1',
          'database': 'some_database',
          'raise_on_warnings': True,
         }
db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;')
cursor.close()

# wait some to make changes to the database using the HeidiSQL workbenches

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('some_SQL_query') # will now read the last committed data
for result in cursor:
    do_something_with(result)
cursor.close()
```

Comment: As setting the isolation level to "READ COMMITTED" seems to be advanced data base use: "Expert users might choose the READ COMMITTED level as they push the boundaries of scalability with OLTP processing"(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level) it may be the better option of refresh the snapshot on which queries are performed by issuing `commit()` before a query.